# Get all post from a post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

For a custom plugin I want a full list of all products we have in WooCommerce. So, I found this code, but it shows only 10 results, instead of all products.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'product', 'post_per_page' => -1));
```

What is the right loop to get all products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$options = array('post_type'.    => 'product', 
                 'post_per_page' => -1,
                 'nopaging' => true, )
$loop    = new WP_Query( $options );
```

This adds `'nopaging' => true,`. See [Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) for more info

Comment: Yeah! Simpel trick and does his job!

Comment: @NVO Great to hear

Comment: And thanks @toscho, I didn't check my markup!